# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

Trying to calculate BMI ( body mass index ) as an app in Swift. Making the calculate function I cannot find the solution

```
@IBOutlet weak var height: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var weight: UITextField!
```

---

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

@IBAction func reset(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

func calculateIMC(){

    var textHeight = height.text
    var textWeight = weight.text
    var intHeight:Int? = Int(textHeight!) ?? 0
    var intWeight:Int? = Int(textWeight!) ?? 0

    let calculateHeight: Int? = (intHeight * intHeight)
}
```

Error message on the last line of code:

Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are the pointless and wrong type annotations. Remove them! All values are non-optional (and constants)

```
func calculateIMC(){

    let textHeight = height.text
    let textWeight = weight.text
    let intHeight = Int(textHeight!) ?? 0
    let intWeight = Int(textWeight!) ?? 0

    let calculateHeight = intHeight * intHeight // probably intHeight * intWeight
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't unwrap a variable if you are not sure that its value is not `nil`. Use `flatMap` to get a required value in one line:

```
func calculateIMC() {
    let textHeight = height.text
    let textWeight = weight.text
    let intHeight = textHeight.flatMap { Int($0) } ?? 0
    let intWeight = textWeight.flatMap { Int($0) } ?? 0
    let calculateHeight = intHeight * intHeight
}
```

All code in this post was tested in Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: We *are sure*. Although it's declared as optional the `text` property of `UITextField` is never `nil`. Apart from that you are converting each single character to `Int` which makes no sense.

Comment: @vadian What if Álvato Valero uses [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint)? In such case by default you should not perform a force unwrapping.

Comment: SwiftLint is not mentioned and even Apple confirms that the `text` property of `UITextField` is never `nil`.